# PageBlockTable causing outputpanel to not rerender

Tags: apex, visualforce, pageblocktable, outputpanel

I have the following in a VF page:

```
        <apex:outputPanel id="tstpopup" >
            <apex:outputPanel styleClass="popupBackground" layout="block" rendered="{!displayPopUp}"/>
            <apex:outputPanel styleClass="custPopup" layout="block" rendered="{!displayPopUp}">
                <apex:pageBlockTable width="500px" value="{!qbWrapperList}" var="qb" id="qbTable">
                    <apex:column >
                        <apex:facet name="header">Add Question</apex:facet>
                        <apex:selectCheckboxes value="{!qb.isChecked}" id="checkbox" />
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column >
                        <apex:facet name="header">Question</apex:facet>                                
                        <apex:outputText value="{!qb.qb.Question__c}" id="question"/>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column >
                        <apex:facet name="header">Answers</apex:facet>
                        <apex:outputText value="{!qb.qb.Answer_Choices__c}" id="answer"/>
                    </apex:column>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!closePopup}" rerender="tstpopup"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!closePopup}" rerender="tstpopup, qbTable"/>
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:outputPanel>
```

The Cancel/Save button methods are simple:

```
public void closePopup() {
    displayPopup = false;
}
```

If I remove the PageBlockTable from the VF code the closePopup works, but with the PageBlockTable nothing happens.

Any help is appreciated.

******Actually realized that my button calls were not getting to the apex method closePopup. I put a debug statement in the method and didn't see anything in the logs. Any idea why that would not work?

Comment: can you specify what is the requirement and what is the specific issue

Comment: I have a popup appear and disappear based on rerendering outputpanels. It works if I remove the PageBlockTable.

Comment: Where is the form without it apex:commandButton  can't be added paste the exact code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Please Check my blog here](http://avionsalesforce.blogspot.com/2014/07/rendering-problem-in-visualforce-pages.html). If you have a panel with rendered condition you need to wrap with another panel without any condition and rerender it.

```
<apex:outputPanel id="outerPanel">
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!someval}" />
</apex:outputPanel>
<apex: form>
 <apex:commandBunnon value ="Test" action ="{!test}" reRended = "outerPanel" />
</apex:form>
```

Comment: good info and the blog

Comment: Thanks, but aren't I already doing that?


`<apex:outputPanel id="tstpopup" >
            <apex:outputPanel styleClass="popupBackground" layout="block" rendered="{!displayPopUp}"/>
            <apex:outputPanel styleClass="custPopup" layout="block" rendered="{!displayPopUp}">`

Comment: Yes, qbTable is a pageBlockTable if it wrapped with an apex:outputPanel it will work from my experience I know rerendering does not work on pageBlockTable all the time

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try giving an **Id** to your nested outputPanels and try to give that Id in **Rendered** attribute of your command buttons. Below is sample modified code. Please try.

```
<apex:outputPanel id="tstpopup" >
        <apex:outputPanel styleClass="popupBackground" layout="block" rendered="{!displayPopUp}" Id="nestedPanelOne"/>
        <apex:outputPanel styleClass="custPopup" layout="block" rendered="{!displayPopUp}">
            <apex:pageBlockTable width="500px" value="{!qbWrapperList}" var="qb" id="qbTable">
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">Add Question</apex:facet>
                    <apex:selectCheckboxes value="{!qb.isChecked}" id="checkbox" />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">Question</apex:facet>                                
                    <apex:outputText value="{!qb.qb.Question__c}" id="question"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">Answers</apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputText value="{!qb.qb.Answer_Choices__c}" id="answer"/>
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
            <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!closePopup}" rerender="tstpopup,nestedPanelOne"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!closePopup}" rerender="tstpopup, nestedPanelOne, qbTable"/>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks. But that didn't work.